# gtk3 animated progress bar not possible?

Tags: linux, gtk, themes, progress-bar, gtk3

In gtk-2 it was possible to make an animated striped progressbar.  Is this really not possible with gtk-3?  I've looked everywhere on the internet and at the gtk-3 documentation and have not found anything that indicates that it is possible.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Post some code. Post some screenshots, link a video.

Comment: I guess he wants something like this http://cssdeck.com/labs/animated-progress-bar

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean, you want the GtkProgressBar pulsing? Use gtk_progress_bar_pulse (GtkProgressBar *widget). If this is about Theming gtk, animation control by the engine. For more animation you have to code the engine yourself, unfortunately, which is same with gtk+-2.0. Read GtkStyleContext documentation for more clearer.